# Start & End of day in local timezone

Tags: node.js, date, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to assign a date range - start/end dates for a process. The catch is that the start date should be the 00:00:00 of the start date and end date should be 23:59:59 of the end date in the timezone that my server is in.

Input is `4/4/2017`

Following is my code snippet,

```
var pEnddate = formatDate (campaign.CMPGN_DTL_TX.CMPGN_END_DT, "yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59");
pEnddate.then (function ( endDate ) {
    var endDate1 = moment.tz (endDate, "America/Phoenix").format ();
    campaign.CMPGN_DTL_TX.CMPGN_END_DT = endDate1;
}
```

It is going good for the first time and saving in UTC as `"CMPGN_END_DT" : ISODate("2017-04-05T06:59:59.000+0000")`

When I try editing it, the next time the date from my TS is coming as `"CMPGN_END_DT" : ISODate("2017-04-05T06:59:59.000+0000")`. But, the date is changing to the next date, which is `CMPGN_END_DT" : ISODate("2017-04-05T23:59:59.000+0000")` because I am hard-coding the time. I'm doing this to ensure I set it to the end of day. Because of this, every time I execute this code (which is when I'm updating the related process), the date is getting incremented by 1.

The only workaround I could figure out was to set it to the EOD without having to hard-code it. Is there some way I can achieve this?

Comment: It did not fully undertsand your question, but probably you can use [`startOf('day')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [`endOf('day')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/).

Comment: `moment().startOf('day');     // set to 12:00 am today
moment().startOf('date');     // set to 12:00 am today`

I thought these returned current date's start and end times. How can I do it for any given day?

Comment: You can use it on every moment object, not only on `moment()`. In your case something like: `moment.tz (endDate, "America/Phoenix").startOf('date').format()`